# Does a Primefaces Linechart Zoom event exist?

Tags: events, primefaces, zooming, linechart

I am trying to use primefaces Linechart zoom feature to retrive portions of data. For instance, say x-axis represents time. If the whole line chart represents data for a week, by zooming in I can get data for say a day or a few hours.

So, I need an actionlistner that fires on zoom event and from which I can retrieve the starting time and endtime of the zoomed portion.

Any clues guyz?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...I guess noboby knows how to...in any case, I found out the answer after a lot of digging and studying...it can be done using javascript...this is how i did it...incase anyone in the future needs it....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".#{request.contextPath}/jsplugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function open(){
                $('#mainForm\\:myPlot').bind('jqplotZoom', function(plot){
                    var minVal = plot.axes.xaxis.min;
                    var maxVal = plot.axes.xaxis.max;
                    //perform any action with these values
                 });
        }
</script>
```

And the primefaces code part -

```
 <p:lineChart id="myPlot"
          value="#{myController.getChartForDialog()}"
          legendPosition=""
          yaxisLabel="Traffic"
          xaxisLabel=""
          zoom="true" 
          extender="open"
          showMarkers="true" 
          seriesColors="ff0000" 
          style="height:200px; width: 100%" />
```

This linechart lies within the form 'mainForm'..

Note: Maybe some of the js imports can be removed. Didn't check it.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an updated version of the previous code. This code basically zooms into a line chart having a date time axis as the xaxis. In case, the difference between the start and the end time stamp is less than a day, then the tick label is changed to *hh:mm* else it is shown as *yy-MM-dd*.

Versions used

- Primefaces 5.3
- jsf 2.1.11
- Wildfly 10

My bean class -

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.AxisType;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.DateAxis;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.LineChartModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.LineChartSeries;

@ManagedBean
public class ChartView implements Serializable {
    private LineChartModel dateModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        createDateModel();
    }

    public LineChartModel getDateModel() {
        return dateModel;
    }

    private void createDateModel() {
        dateModel = new LineChartModel();
        LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
        series1.setLabel("Series 1");

        series1.set("2014-01-01", 51);
        series1.set("2014-01-06", 22);
        series1.set("2014-01-12", 65);
        series1.set("2014-01-18", 74);
        series1.set("2014-01-24", 24);
        series1.set("2014-01-30", 51);

        LineChartSeries series2 = new LineChartSeries();
        series2.setLabel("Series 2");

        series2.set("2014-01-01", 32);
        series2.set("2014-01-06", 73);
        series2.set("2014-01-12", 24);
        series2.set("2014-01-18", 12);
        series2.set("2014-01-24", 74);
        series2.set("2014-01-30", 62);

        dateModel.addSeries(series1);
        dateModel.addSeries(series2);

        dateModel.setTitle("Zoom for Details");
        dateModel.setZoom(true);
        dateModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Values");
        DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Dates");
        axis.setTickAngle(-50);
        axis.setMax("2014-02-01");
        axis.setTickFormat("%y-%m-%d");
        axis.setTickCount(10);

        dateModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
        dateModel.setExtender("open");
    }
}
```

My xhtml class containing the js code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>PrimeFaces</h1>

        <h:form id="mainForm">

            <script type="text/javascript">
            function open(){
                $('#mainForm\\:myPlot').bind('jqplotZoom', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, plot, cursor){
                    var minVal = plot.axes.xaxis.min;
                    var maxVal = plot.axes.xaxis.max;

                    var timeDiff = Math.abs(maxVal - minVal);
                    var dayDiff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                    console.log(dayDiff);

                    if(dayDiff == 1){
                        plot.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString="%H:%M";
                        plot.replot();
                    }
                    console.log(plot.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString);
                });
            }
            </script>

            <p:chart type="line" id="myPlot" model="#{chartView.dateModel}" style="height:300px;" widgetVar="chart"/>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.